# How to reference C# variables in the HTML markup in a Blazor application?

Tags: blazor

As in the title.

1. How should I reference local C# variables in HTML?
2. How should I reference static C# variables in HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there something specific you are having trouble with? You can reference both static and non static variables in your HTML the normal way with an @.

Here's a working example:

```
@page "/test"
<div>
    @StaticVar
</div>

<div>
    @LocalVar
</div>

@code {
    private static string StaticVar = "StaticVar";

    private string LocalVar = "LocalVar";
}
```